# Bronze of Reversal

Tags: feature-request, badges

Is there a Bronze version of the Reversal badge? All the other Gold badges have a bronze and silver equivalent, but not this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Silver Reversal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27862/silver-reversal)

What would you like the criteria to be? +5 to a -2?

I mean, we're already talking some diluted badges, and gamification works best when the goals are hard. If we make it easy for everyone to have tons of badges, the badges mean a lot less.

Comment: Right - so someone's asked it on meta.SO already. Cool. And yeah - I'd've thought having bronze & silver versions of Reversal would encourage people to try to give helpful answers to poor questions.

Comment: @RobFarley - TBH I'm not sure incentivising good answers to bad questions is a useful idea anyway. Better they get closed or edited into shape by the OP before being answered IMO so the questioner makes more effort in future.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough.